# Can't get json through ajax and flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

I am trying to make a simple web application for logs show. On the web side: python 3.4 and flask and on the client side it's simple web form with ajax.

Flask:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/json_test', methods=['GET'])
def json_test():
    return open('log.json').read()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('layout.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My HTML form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type=text/javascript src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{
  url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}">\x3C/script>')</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
  $LOG = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>


<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('a#log').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON($LOG + '/json_test',
                function(data){
                    $("#logs").text(data.result);
                    });
                    return false;
            });
  });
</script>


<p>
    <span id=logs>Logs should be here</span>
    <a href=# id=log>take log</a>
</p>
</html>
```

And my JSON example:

```js
{
"data":
{
    "misc":
    [
        {
            "name" : "JSON 1",
            "type" : "1"
        },

        {
            "name" : "JSON 2",
            "type" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I wanna send a part of logs every 5 second. For this, I plan to use js function: setInterval. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data has no `result` key. You have a `data` key instead.

Placing the `data.data` result in the `<span>` will only insert the text `[object Object]` however; you need to insert actual text. You could turn the object back to JSON text perhaps, using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
$("#logs").text(JSON.stringify(data.data));
```

or you could send something more meaningful instead.